# Progress bar for scp command

Tags: ssh, clipboard, scp

Is there any way to display a progress bar while copying from server to local (or vice versa) using `scp`?

Comment: Now i am getting the percentage.But i need a progress bar.

Comment: there's a script around but i have no idea how to make it work though

Comment: You might be able to alter this script for a progress bar for 'cp'`: http://chris-lamb.co.uk/2008/01/24/can-you-get-cp-to-give-a-progress-bar-like-wget/

Comment: scp -r doesn't show progress bar but it gives a percentage of each file

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I don't think that this can be done with `scp`. Last time I needed something like this i.e. progress shown, I used `rsync` instead. It shows progress in a bar-like manner. See if it works for you.

You will need to use the `--progress` option of `rsync`. You can use the following command:

```
rsync -r -v --progress -e ssh user@remote-system:/address/to/remote/file /home/user/
```

Comment: I was going to post something similar but when I tested it, I just got `2741851   0%  700.39kB/s    0:17:21` and no graphical progress bar (what I think the OP wants).

Comment: @Oli: I think its because you are copying a very small file. Copying ends before rsync can show progress. If you copy a bigger file then you should get a progress bar.

Comment: 5341184   7%  301.09kB/s    0:03:42    
I am getting like this.But it showing the remaining time..really helpful

Comment: For anybody who was looking for cp with progress bar, rsync works great locally, so this answers that question also!  (Just leave off the `-e ssh user@remote-system:` for a local copy and `man rsync` explains the many, many options)

Comment: rsync works great and I use it for such things. If you get `protocol version mismatch`, make sure the target machine's .bashrc isn't printing anything to stdout.

Comment: If you want to connect to a different SSH port than the default, you can use something like `rsync -avz --progress -e 'ssh -p 1223' root@google.com:/foobar.txt ./my-local-copy.txt`

Comment: rsync -Pave "ssh -p 1223"  root@google.com:/foobar.txt ./my-local-copy.txt

Comment: From man `Typically, rsync is configured to use ssh by default` so i guess no need for `-e ssh`

Comment: why use `rsync ` while you just need to add `-v` to `scp`

Comment: @SamirSabri, adding `-v` to `scp` shows the SSH debug messages too. That might be too much information for OP.

Comment: FWIW, `rsync` outputs the progress to `/dev/stderr`, with each update to the progress being "overwritten" with `\r`. In my backup script where I have XFS dumps SCP to the backup host, I use `2>&1` to write the progress to the log file. `cat`ing or `less`ing the log file doesn't display the progress correctly, so using `sed 's_\r_\n_g' XfsBackup.log` shows each progress update on its own line.

Answer (score 124):

The `-v` switch works fine.

Example:

> 5% 9232KB 357.5KB/s   07:48 ETA

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when using `-3`.

Comment: @fuero `man scp`: "`-3` ​ ​ ​ ​ Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host. Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts. **Note that this option disables the progress meter.**"

Comment: This also doesn't work if you have many smaller files

Answer (score 32):

As of 2018, progress and ETA are shown by default and could be disabled by `-q`

Comment: not on macos, lol!

Comment: With this, do you mean overall progress or on a per-file basis? I only see it on a per-file basis in my freshly installed Debian 9.

Comment: except when using `-3`

Comment: For some reason I can see the progress when I run `scp` in a terminal, but when it is running as part of a `cloud-init` script, I don't see any progress (with `curl` I did see progress)... any idea why?  And how to show progress even in a `cloud-init` process?

Comment: @Drachenfels at least as of the latest macOS (Ventura at the moment), it does show the progress and ETA by default.

Comment: ....but not when you copy from 1 remote to another?

Comment: Xubuntu 20.04, copying locally from USB to USB device, with -pr and -l for rate limiting => no it doesn't, there's no progress displayed.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to do this in a command line. I'm sure it's possible but there is a graphical method for doing this.

Nautilus (the default file browser in Ubuntu) can mount ssh/sftp servers. They act like a local filesystem after that and you can copy files around like you normally would. And you get the usual progress bar that you would with a normal copy.

Look under the `File` menu for `Connect to server...`